# GPUImageNormalBlendFilter issue

Tags: ios, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I am using GPUImage Famewark and in which, when I use  GPUImageNormalBlendFilter with still camera, image in not showing on camera to record video while when I use other blend such as overlay, add, etc... Image is showing perfectly with the blend...

My code is as below:

```
 self.filter = [[GPUImageNormalBlendFilter alloc] init];
    self.picture1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[CommonFunction GetImageFromApp:editImage] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];

    [picture1 addTarget:filter];
    [picture1 processImage];

[stillCamera addTarget: filter];

[filter addTarget:self.filterView];
```

Can you have succession for this issue....???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by replacing sequences of code statements which is as below:

```
[stillCamera addTarget: filter];

    [picture1 addTarget:filter];
[picture1 processImage];

[filter addTarget:self.filterView];
```

Thanks